# moving from bzr to git: how to put a branch on top of another one

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bazaar

I have searched a solution for weeks, but I wasn't lucky.

I have a bazaar repo with 5 years of history (up to 2011). When I started working on this project (2011), I was using svn, so the "manager" just gave me a tarball with the sources of the "master" (it has been impossibile to convert the project in svn). I set up an svn repo from that tarball and I worked on it until last month.
I switched to git recently, converting both the svn and git repos in two git repos.

Now I have two git repositories: the former bzr repo, covering 2006-2011, and my repo, covering 2011-2016. What I would like to do is to have a linear history on the master, i.e. I would like to put my master (with attached branches) "on top" of the former bzr repo.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. First, convert the bzr repo to git.  You will have two repos, let's call them proj-bzr and proj-git.
2. In proj-git, add proj-bzr as a remote, and fetch it.  Hopefully, the last commit of proj-bzr and the first commit of proj-git have the same files.
3. Add a graft which sets the latest proj-bzr commit as a parent to the oldest proj-git commit.  See: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint
4. Once you are convinced that this is the correct history, you can use filter-branch to "bake" the graft into the repository and make it permanent.  This will rewrite all of the SHA-1 hashes of proj-git.

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to do it with `git replace`, but is it not permanent, and also tagging is not permanent. Could you explain a little the fourth point?

Comment: A graft doesn't change history, and it doesn't get copied when you clone a repo.